# Node.js/JavaScript Stubbing of Built-in Types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, monkeypatching, stubbing

This exercise is fairly academic, but it's useful in understanding JavaScript's behavior.

Why does this work:

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.log(fs.readdirSync('/').length); //approximately '28' on my Macbook
fs['readdirSync'] = function(){ return ['/tmp', '/bin']; };
console.log(fs.readdirSync('/').length); //'2' as expected
```

and this doesn't:

```
var a = "hello world";
console.log(a.length); //'11'
a['length'] = 1000;
console.log(a.length); //still '11'... why??
```

I know it's possible to monkeypatch JavaScript built-in types such as String, but is it possible to stub them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of [TJ Holowaychuk](https://twitter.com/#!/tjholowaychuk/status/128854351237234689): Strings are immutable. So it seems like it's not possible in this manner.